# When I run Django on Dreamhost using SQLite, why do I get an OperationalError telling me that a table doesn’t exist?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, dreamhost

I had a Django site running on Dreamhost. Although I used SQLite when developing locally, I initially used MySQL on Dreamhost, because that’s what [the wiki page](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django) said to do, and because if I’m using an ORM, I might as well take advantage of it by running against a different database.

After a while, I switched the settings on the server to use SQLite, to make it easier to keep my development database in sync with the server one. `python manage.py syncdb` worked on the server, but when I tried to access the site, I got an `OperationalError`. The Django error page said that one of my tables didn’t exist.

I checked the database using sqlite on the command line on the server, and using `python manage.py shell`, and both worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that on the server, the `DATABASE_NAME` setting required a full path, e.g.

```
DATABASE_NAME = '/home/USERNAME/SITE/DJANGOPROJECT/DATABASE.db'
```

Locally (and I guess for manage.py on the server), just a filename was fine, e.g.

```
DATABASE_NAME = 'DATABASE.db'
```

Comment: A helper method like this can help reduce path name tweaks between environments:  `rel = lambda *x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)`